# How to recover a consumer with RabbitMQ-JMS, or specify a custom Exception Handler?

Tags: jakarta-ee, rabbitmq, jms

I'm trying to use the RabbitMQ-JMS client and intentionally have created a long onMessage() listener to see how the client will recover.

```
        Context context = new InitialContext();
        rabbitMQ = (RMQConnectionFactory)context.lookup("java:global/jms/ConnectionFactory");
        queue = (Queue)context.lookup("java:global/mq/kodo");

        connection = rabbitMQ.createConnection();
        connection.start();
        Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

        MessageConsumer consumer = session.createConsumer(queue);
        consumer.setMessageListener(new MessageListener() {

            @Override
            public void onMessage(Message message) {
                Thread.sleep(20000);
            }
        });
```

I see the DeliveryExecutor class having a timeout on processing the message, and in its exception handler, one of the things it does is to close the channel, thereby dropping my consumer.

Based on the [RabbitMQ docs](https://www.rabbitmq.com/api-guide.html), the client is supposed to auto-recover, but I guess these situations are not handled the same way.  To make it worse, the RabbitMQ-JMS client seems intentionally designed to prevent me from specifying my own ExceptionHandler to avoid this behavior.

Is there another way to handle this kind of exception handling via the JMS API?  (I tried added an ExceptionListener on the jms.Connection, but it is never called).

Am I stuck?  How am I supposed to detect that my consumer died and try to reconnect?  How can I ensure that there is some form of automatic recovery for my listener?

Comment: Eric, you could try to post in RabbitMQ user group  to get a quick answer : [https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/rabbitmq-users](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/rabbitmq-users).

Comment: You could also maintain a custom pool of Message consumers, set with a min of alive MessageConsumers with the help of commons-pool as a workaround